# Setting Email Body With a String Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have 5 view controllers, and you input your name on the second view controller, and I want it to transfer onto the fifth view controller where you actually sent the email. example, Screen 2: "Bob", screen 5: "Hi There, letting you know 'Bob' will be away today", but it keeps giving me an error: 
value of type 'String' has no member text.

This is my Second view controller where you input your name:

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func nextButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "whotoclass", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var secondVC: FifthScreenViewController = segue.destination as! FifthScreenViewController

    secondVC.receivedString = textField.text!
}
```

and it gives me this:

[image]

How do I fix this error? am I transferring the data correctly?

Comment: receivedString is a String object and it doesn't need .text,  simply use it like "Name : \\(receivedString)"